# Existence of a solution to a given system of equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

[image]

Can someone help me with the solutions of 1.9?

Regarding 1.10, I think **c** fails because if we take $A=\{a_{ij}\}_{ij}$ to be the 3*3 matrix with $a_{11}=a,$ and $a_{33}=b$ and otherwise $a_{ij}=0$ where $a+b \neq 0$, then **c** is not satisifed in general. Right?

P.S-I am unable to type properly because some functions on my laptop is not working well. That is why I didn't define the matrix properly and also I could not type the full question. So Sorry about that!

Answer (score 1):

**1.9**

> If a solution $X$ exists, then $AX$ is a projection onto $im\,A$ and
>   $I-AX$ is a projection onto $\ker A$, so $\mathbb R^n = \ker A\oplus im\,A$.

*Proof.* $(AX)^2 = A(XAX) = AX$. So, also $I-AX$ is a projection. Certainly, $AX$ maps into $im\,A$. If $y\in im\,A$, $y=Ax$, then $AXy = AXAx = Ax = y$, so $AX$ indeed maps onto $im\,A$. To see that $I-AX$ maps onto $\ker A$, we observe that $A(I-AX) = A(I-XA) = A-AXA = 0$, so $I-AX$ maps into $\ker A$. If $x\in\ker A$, then $(I-XA)x = x-XAx = x$, hence it maps onto.

(a) true. If $A\neq 0$ were nilpotent, there would exist $x,y\in\mathbb R^n$, $x\neq 0$, such that $Ay = x$ and $Ax=0$, hence $x\in\ker A\cap im\,A = \{0\}$. Contradiction!

(b) true. Choose $X=A$.

(c) true. $A$ is singular, so $\ker A\neq\{0\}$ and non-zero, so both $\ker A$ and $im\,A$ are one-dimensional and $A$-invariant. Take $x\in\ker A$, $x\neq 0$, and $y\in im\,A$, $y\neq 0$. Then $\{x,y\}$ is a basis with resp. to which $A$ is diagonal.

**1.10**

(a) I don't understand the claim.

(b) I cannot read that.

(c) true. $A\in M_2(\mathbb R)$ has a one-dimensional kernel because it's singular and non-zero. Let $x\in\ker A$, $x\neq 0$. If there was $y$ such that $Ay = x$, then $A$ is similar to $(\begin{smallmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{smallmatrix})$ and hence $tr\,A=0$. So, $\ker A\cap im\,A=\{0\}$, that is, $\mathbb R^2 = \ker A\oplus im\,A$. Let $y\in im\,A$. Then $Ay\in im\,A$, so $Ay=cy$ for some $c\in\mathbb R\backslash\{0\}$. Clearly, $tr\,A = c$. So, we have to show that $c^{-2}A^3 = A$. So, let $z\in\mathbb R^2$, $z=ax+by$. Then $c^{-2}A^3z = bc^{-2}A^3y = bc^{-2}c^3y = bcy = bAy = Az$.

Comment: regarding c, I have another explaination, that is since A is signular, then 0 is an eigenvalue. and since it is non-zero, then it has a non-zero eigenvalue. Thus two eigenvalues are different. Hence it is diagonalisable

Comment: and can you say something about 1.10. Especially [c]. I think that $\frac{A}{trace[A]^2}$ need not be a solution

Comment: @SunShine That's also a good reasoning, yes.

Comment: I have edited my answer. (c) is true.